# How to hide padding devoted to scrollbars that don't appear?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, macos, google-chrome

I've got a frustrating issue here involving a `nav` element that always displays an area to contain a scrollbar, even when the scrollbar is not needed. Here's what it looks like when all the content is displaying:

[image: Nav element with scrollbar area visible]

Here's what it looks like when you reduce the height of the window so scrolling is necessary to see all the content:

[image: Nav element with scrollbar visible]

And here's what it SHOULD look like:

[image: Nav element with no scrollbar area visible]

Here's the CSS for this element (as written in React and including some variables I'm leaving in -- I'm assuming those shouldn't matter):

```
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: ${Color.White};
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: calc(100vh - ${heightCorrection});
  padding: 0 16px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: scroll;

  width: ${width};
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;

  > header,
  footer {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
```

I created that third screenshot by changing `overflow: scroll` to `overflow: hidden`, but that prevents me from being able to scroll when I need to, and I still need that to happen.

I should mention that a frustrating thing about this issue is that most users haven't been able to replicate it. I don't have any particularly unusual setup; I'm running the latest version of Chrome on MacOS. But others with very similar configurations aren't seeing that empty scrollbar area. This issue stumped one of the best front-end developers I know (who can't replicate it), so I thought I'd try here and see if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't get any traction on this, but in case anyone lands on it, the answer is simply to change `overflow: scroll` to `overflow: auto`.